# Uno-Platform - Debugging WASM - Is this a configuration issue, expected error, or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, uno-platform, webassembly

> WebAssembly.Net.Debugging.DevToolsProxy: Error: sending error response for id: msg-163B54A9DE82BF1FBD5A89BDBAE9E87:::71 -> [Result: IsOk: False, IsErr: True, Value: , Error: {
> "code": -32000,
> "message": "Violations are not supported for this target"
> } ]

My app works as expected under UWP, however when run under WASM the UI is never rendered (stuck on splashscreen). When debugging in the browser, I see no errors in the console and none of my breakpoints are hit. I'm attempting to follow the guidance here https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap#how-to-use-the-visual-studio-2019-debugger but after breaking on exceptions in DebugStore.cs and BrowserDebugProxy.cs this is where I'm at.

Is this an expected error as in I'm trying to do something I'm not suppose to?

A configuration error as in I missed something?

Or my actual error as in this is my problem and I need to troubleshoot it?

Latest version of VS 2019, Chrome, Windows 10 19041.450, and nuget packages

Thank You

Comment: Usual question: which version of Uno dependencies are you using? I mean the version of Uno.UI.WebAssembly and Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap

Comment: Uno.UI.WebAssembly = v3.0.5  Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap = v1.3.4 Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap.DevServer = v1.3.4  while I haven't solved the devtoolsproxy error I think my issue is with threading, even though my IO calls aren't failing I'm not regaining execution of the UI...still throubleshooting